# Can I split a tensor dynamically in a variable number of parts with tf.sparse_split?

Tags: python, tensorflow

I have a 3D sparse tensor in Tensorflow which I want to split along the first dimension (axis=0). I was thinking of using [`tf.sparse_split`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/sparse_split) operation. But it requires an argument `num_splits` as `Python integer`. I wanted to know if I have the `num_splits` in a scalar placeholder is there any way to use it?

Why such a convention has been followed for this function, I haven't seen this in any other tensorflow operation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the tensorflow framework, `num_splits` has to be known at graph building time, because the graph is meant to be static. At least when using daddy's old, graph-based tensorflow. If you really have to have parts of your graph that are dynamic, you might success using tensorflow's imperative [eager execution](https://www.tensorflow.org/programmers_guide/eager).